# eslint 8 to honor top-level await

Tags: node.js, async-await, eslint

i am using [top-level `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#top_level_await) in my [nodejs module](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/packages.html#type)

> You can use the `await` keyword on its own (outside of an async function) within a JavaScript module.

> Files ending with `.js` are loaded as ES modules when the nearest parent `package.json` file contains a top-level field `"type"` with a value of `"module"`

```sh
$ jq -r '.type' package.json
module

$ node --version
v16.14.2

$ npm --version
8.7.0

$ jq -r '.devDependencies.eslint' package.json
8.12.0
```

when i run eslint, which should have [a support for top-level `await`](https://eslint.org/blog/2021/06/whats-coming-in-eslint-8.0.0#support-for-es2022-class-fields-top-level-await-and-regexp-matching-indices), i get the error

> Parsing error: Cannot use keyword 'await' outside an async function

how do i make eslint honor top-level `await`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Make sure that:

- You are using ESLint >=8.
- You have the correct [parser options](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-parser-options): `ecmaVersion` should be `2022` or `"latest"`, and `sourceType` should be `"module"` (ESLint does not respect the `"type": "module"` setting in `package.json` files).

Next time you have a question about ESLint, please, show your ESLint configuration (typically `.eslintrc.json` or `.eslintrc.yml`) to get more specific advice.